# Auto resize gridview height?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, android-gridview

I created a gridview with 2 columns  and 3 rows wich contains images with text.
[image]

Everthing works great.. But the problem is when I try with another kind of screen...
I have a Moto X 2013 and the images have 192x192 px and the gridview looks great

With a moto G2 I have a scroll into de gridview and **I don't want it**

I put this sizes for the image in the respectives drawable folders:
xxhdpi - 240x240 px
xhdpi - 192x192 px
hdpi  - 144x144 px
mdpi  - 92x92 px

And I have the same problem. Why this size for the phone? Because I want the gridview looks like the picture, fill the height(so I try with differents size to know how is the correct for my phone) but the Moto G2 disappoint me. If i put the image size smaller than 192x192 the gridview not gonna finish at the bottom of the screen.

This is my

grid_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#455A64"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_marginTop= "10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/style_spinner"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Ciudad: "
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView34"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/spn_ciudad"
                android:layout_weight="0.95" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridViewMainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:numColumns="2"/>



</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

GridViewAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final List<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

public GridViewAdapter (Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mItems.add(new Item("Buscar por complejos",       R.drawable.clock));
    mItems.add(new Item("Buscar por horarios",   R.drawable.clock));
    mItems.add(new Item("Buscar por localizacion", R.drawable.clock));
    mItems.add(new Item("Ver ultimas operaciones",R.drawable.clock));
    mItems.add(new Item("Green",R.drawable.clock));
    clock.add(new Item("Cyan",      R.drawable.clock));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

@Override
public Item getItem(int i) {
    return mItems.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return mItems.get(i).drawableId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = view;
    ImageView picture;
    TextView name;

    if (v == null) {
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);
        v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
        v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
    }

    picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
    name = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.text);

    Item item = getItem(i);

    picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
    name.setText(item.name);

    return v;
}

private static class Item {
    public final String name;
    public final int drawableId;

    Item(String name, int drawableId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.drawableId = drawableId;
    }
}
}
```

This is how Moto G2 looks like (Do you see the scroll bar?, and if the screen is smaller than the Moto G2, the scroll is much more!):
[image]

**Any solution for my problem? Thanks for helping me!**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding android:numColumns="auto_fit" and   android:stretchMode="columnWidth" and setting GridView's parent height to MATCH_PARENT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Example code from http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: Not workin :(, also I need two columns, no more than that